# TeamCity: How to run tests projects in parallel

Tags: automated-tests, nunit, teamcity

I have 4 test projects and wanna run all of them on TeamCity in parallel.

So can I do that? If I can then how?

It is ok parallel execution by fixtures on all test projects, but I hope that I can run these vstest.console commands in parallel?
[vstest.console command does run here not in parallel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1CAeC.png)

Comment: May I need to use some selenium RC or something like PNUnit? A good link with helpful guide how to run tests in parallel from 4 other projects if it is possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All what we need is:

1. 1 console runner step
2. vs build tools (`vstest.console.exe`)

To run 4 dll's in parallel all what we need is call in cmd vstest.console.exe with 4 dll files separated by space.
Like this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/vstest-console-options?view=vs-2019#code-try-1

We can log them using parameters `/logger:logger://teamcity /logger:console;verbosity=normal`

So final command looks like:

```
<path_to_vstest.console> vstest.console.exe MSTest.dll UnitTest1.dll UnitTest2.dll UnitTest3.dll /logger:logger://teamcity /logger:console;verbosity=normal /Parallel
```

Answer (score 0):

My answer might not be applicable for your case, depending on resources you have.
My idea requires you to have 4 agents running, so you can use them in parallel.

To do so, you want is to create 4 builds config (one for each of yours parallel run) (named : testRun0, testRun1, testRun2, testRun3).
Then you can add another build config (could be named: "testReport")  that has the 4 others as a "snapshot dependency".

in that case, every time a trigger occurs in the 5th build config, it will trigger the 4 other first.

there is a good example in the jetbrain doc: https://blog.jetbrains.com/teamcity/2019/10/build-chains-teamcitys-blend-of-pipelines-part-2-running-builds-in-parallel/
look at "Composite build configuration" part.

Comment: Thanks for good idea. I have another one. So I want create a bat file that runs all tests from command line, and in teamcity would be a console runner step who call that bat file. It is very simple olution I hope that it will work)